# Removing duplicates from strings based on container [] {} ()

Tags: php, regex

Line contains token inside Braces , Brackets , Parentheses and though they may share same number but they denote different subjects, i.e `[10]` and `(10)` are different. **The goal is to write a program which removes duplicates from a line but not disturbing their order**.

Sample input

```
# [1] {1} [2] {10} [3] [3] [4] {10} {100} [1] [5]
# [5] {1} [6] (10) (20) (10) {10} [7] [5] [6] {10} {100} [8] [5] (10) (30)
# (10) (30) [7] {1} [8] {10} [9] [7] [8] {100} {101} [9] [5] {101} (50)
```

Desired output

```
# [1] {1} [2] {10} [3] [4] {100} [5]
# [5] {1} [6] (10) (20) {10} [7] {100} [8] (30)
# (10) (30) [7] {1} [8] {10} [9] {100} {101} [5] (50)
```

Below the code can be used to remove duplicates numbers inside Parentheses, but not for Braces or brackets.

```
$re = '/\((\d+)\)/';
 if (preg_match_all($re, $details_, $matches)) {
    print_r(($matches[1]));  
}
```

Comment: `\((\d+)\)` works as you intend? That seems to give back all numbers still that are in `()`, regardless of dup.

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, it works for XAMPP Version: 8.0.7 on Win 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$input = '[1] {1} [2] {10} [3] [3] [4] {10} {100} [1] [5]';

$result = array_unique(explode(' ', $input));
```

Edit: Added two solutions for cases where there are no or multiple spaces.

The first solution preservers whitespaces as they are in the input string:

```
$result = array_reduce(
  str_split($input),
  function (array $carry, string $char) {
    return match ( $char ) {
      '(', '{', '[' => [ $carry[0], $char ],
      ')', '}', ']' => str_contains($carry[0], $carry[1] . $char)
                       ? $carry
                       : [ $carry[0] . $carry[1] . $char, '' ],
      ' '           => [ $carry[0] . ' ', '' ],
      default       => [ $carry[0], $carry[1] . $char ]
    };
  },
  [ '', '' ]
)[0];
```

The second one is variation, inserting one space between each item:

```
$result = array_reduce(
  str_split($input),
  function (array $carry, string $char) {
    return match ( $char ) {
      '(', '{', '[' => [ $carry[0], $char ],
      ')', '}', ']' => str_contains($carry[0], $carry[1] . $char)
                       ? $carry
                       : [ $carry[0] . ( $carry[0] === '' ? '' : ' ' ) . $carry[1] . $char, '' ],
      default       => [ $carry[0], $carry[1] . $char ]
    };
  },
  [ '', '' ]
)[0];
```

Comment: Both the code works well, but selected this at it was a bit faster in my case.

Comment: Can it be fixed to work in case there is no space between those numbers or multiple spaces between, i.e [10]    [1]    [1]    {1} [2] {10} [3][3]

Comment: @www.friend0.in Added additional solutions to reflect irregular whitespaces between the items.

Answer (score 2):

You could match the format of the lines and use a pattern with capture 3 groups, where you would use the values of group 1 and group 2

```
^(#\h*)((\[\d+]|\{\d+}|\(\d+\))(?:\h+(?3))*)$
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(#\h*)` Capture **group 1**, match `#` and optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(\[\d+]|\{\d+}|\(\d+\))` Capture **group 3**, match either digits between square brackets, curly braces or parenthesis
  - `(?:\h+(?3))*` Repeat 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and recurse the group 3 pattern
- `)` Close group 2
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wcTbqg/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/K0Wif).

For example:

```
$re = '/^(#\h*)((\[\d+]|\{\d+}|\(\d+\))(?:\h+(?3))*)$/m';
$str = '# [1] {1} [2] {10} [3] [3] [4] {10} {100} [1] [5]
# [5] {1} [6] (10) (20) (10) {10} [7] [5] [6] {10} {100} [8] [5] (10) (30)
# (10) (30) [7] {1} [8] {10} [9] [7] [8] {100} {101} [9] [5] {101} (50)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
echo implode("\n", array_map(fn($x) => $x[1] . implode(' ', array_unique(explode(' ', $x[2]))), $matches));
```

Output

```
# [1] {1} [2] {10} [3] [4] {100} [5]
# [5] {1} [6] (10) (20) {10} [7] {100} [8] (30)
# (10) (30) [7] {1} [8] {10} [9] {100} {101} [5] (50)
```

If there are more than 1 spaces to split on, you can use `preg_split('/\h+/', $x[2])` instead of explode.

Comment: Works well but outputs only the last line :( on Win10 XAMP

Comment: @www.friend0.in Which php version are you on?

Comment: PHP Version 8.0.7, but it works perfectly in the link you provided :/

Comment: If you run this code, do you get the same? https://3v4l.org/AkCAe

Comment: Works like a charm in the link :) but not on Win 10

Comment: I copied your code and tried, it showed only the last line but in the all the links you provided, it worked perfectly.

Comment: The problem lies in implode("\n",...... , the code works perfectly if I add the \n at the end of the line, like this [5]"."\n"."# [5]

Comment: @www.friend0.in You can use this change `\r?$` See https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=TVBNb4JAEL2T8B8mQsKMkspHbW2t5VLSYxvaG7slRLfFBJCiJjbqf3eXVethZ3bfvPd2Zp6ipmhMwzTsVsAUnOEXWqzoEyJL2XzA92wn02HPUCZGhNEjKwYYhUR9Ym1kDytnItWrdavkFqQ-h51_gDRQ2ZOXkOtzewJkULDkpSNuGpZKWnLHAX2PAAMV1E073HfUrn7tMNawloQeKa_Lo1N1ruNzIw9cW2lA-_gnvGtBvXDkkZrINJpW_GRVvp4VWV6WKBfkgppTxg4VKxfek_g1-4g_s7fkJU5c8EhKxaxYwqJqyuVcYI_VPRfyts3_pFmD3zXaW4LpM9hbtYObC9MB50zc1IvfjUCxvapIesCJ6P97oskR&v=8.1.3

Comment: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=TVBNT8JAEL036X-YtE06A420VBStyEXiUVO9ddemgdWSlFILJBjgv7MfgBx2Pt6-93Z2nsZN2diWbXmtgBH4vS90WdkhRJaxWZfv2U6mw56hTIwIx4-s7OI4JuqQ11v4iZSu1q3UOi5kEYdddICsr3Ioi5ibc3sCZFCw5GUDbluuSkZyxwGjkAD7KqjKONxrqr6_dhga2EjikJTXpdEq7To8D_LAjZUBjE90wvUIqsNBSE6i1tG04idfFOtpmRdVhXI7Aah_yqhRsQrgPZ285h-Tz_wtfZmkAYQkpWJaLmG-aKrlTKDDaieAom2LP2nW4HeN3pZg9AzeVu3g5sL0wT8TN_X8dyNQbK9uJL3Piej_eaLkCA%2C%2C&v=8.1.3

Comment: @www.friend0.in The line with the pattern should be `$re = '/^(#\h*)((\[\d+]|\{\d+}|\(\d+\))(?:\h+(?3))*)\r?$/m';` See https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com?s=TVBNT8JAEL2T9D9M2iadgUbaIopW7EXiUVO9ddemgdWS8FELJBjgvzPbBeSw8_H2vbez85RUZWW1rJZbKxiC1_1CR5RtQhSZmHTkXuw4HfYCOQkiTB5F2cGkR9QmUSdud-7FrF6ta5bbDmShhF14gCzSOeCiJ825PQEcNMy8rC-tlqOTkdxJwDAgwEgHXRmH-4ba3F87DAxsJL2AtNelaVSN6-A8yIM0VgYwPuEJb0bQHfYDsmO9kapWP_m8WI_LvJjNkBfkg_4nxwZVKx_e09Fr_jH6zN_Sl1HqQ0AsVeNyCdN5NVtOFNpiYftQ1HXxx2YVfi_Q3RIMn8Hd6h3cXJgeeGfiZjH93ShU26sbpkeSiP6fJ4qP&v=8.1.3

Comment: This code works even in case of no space or multiple spaces in input

Comment: @Thefourthbird Can you help me in this https://3v4l.org/s6dRC#v8.0.17

Comment: @www.friend0.in Hi there, sure..the quantifier for the horizontal whitespace chars should be 0 or more times using `\h*` like `$re = '/^(#\h*)((\[\d+]|\{\d+}|\(\d+\))(?:\h*(?3))*)\r?$/m';`  in that case. See https://3v4l.org/1WfZl#v8.0.17